# How to add live streaming video to a django website? Red5?

Tags: python, django, video-streaming, red5, live-streaming

I've created a website using Django, and I'm at the point where I wanted to add the live streaming video component, since my website is centered around users being able to stream videos that other users can watch.  I essentially have the entire website ready to go except for the video part, which I can't seem to figure out.  I installed Red5 server into my computer and Flash Media Live Encoder, but can't seem to figure out if/how to use Red5 in my project. Can anyone offer me any help or advice on what I should be doing?  I have been trying to get a grasp on what it is I need to do to add the video functionality to my website, but have just been running in circles, unable to figure out the right solution.  For one, the majority of information I can find is about being able to broadcast myself, which is not what I intend to do (my users are going to be the ones broadcasting).  Again, the website is still in development since it is missing this major piece, which I can't figure out, but it is all I have left to solve before my website is finished.  I don't mind other options, I just need a solution that will enable me to finish this project.  I really appreciate any help anyone can provide me, or even just links to good resources.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @GetItDone
I'm just at the same point as you in the moment of your question. I really need to add live cam streaming to my web application (build with Django), for muticasting video (one to many).
How did you solved it?
Thanks in advance ;-)

Comment: Hi @GetItDone i have the same problem place share it with other ...

Answer (score 3):

I am sorry but your question is likely to be down-voted by the audience, stackoverflow is not the right place for such requests. Your questions are way to general to give a concrete answer.

We are working on an Open Source Video Conferencing app based on Red5:
http://incubator.apache.org/openmeetings/
And it has a SOAP/REST API to integrate:
http://incubator.apache.org/openmeetings/SoapRestAPI.html
as well as plugins for example for Drupal:
http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/drupal-plugin-openmeetings/

You might use that instead of coding your own one, cause it has already installation instructions and an active community around it that you can ask for further help if you are new to red5 and video streaming.

Sebastian